# Only wild card search is working in solr

Tags: solr, solrj

I've indexed few docs using SolrJ, now I want to search the same index using SolrJ.. I am not using embedded server..

I cannot even get results through their web based panel for my index.

ps : btw, the indexing is going fine, I checked that they were indexed by running a wild card search `"*:*"` through the query..

Here is the search snippet :

```
try {
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("from:a");
        query.addSortField("id", SolrQuery.ORDER.asc);
        QueryResponse rsp = server.query(query);
        SolrDocumentList docs = rsp.getResults();
        System.out.println(docs.getNumFound());
            String[] a = new String[100];
            System.out.println(docs.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is [schema.xml](http://cid-230da956ce9fd436.office.live.com/self.aspx/StackOverflow/schema.xml) 
Tell me if the link doesn't work...

Comment: can you get results for any query at all (other that `*:*`)? can you post your schema.xml?

Comment: No and yes. tell me how do I post that huge xml ? Is there a way to attach files here or should I post it somewhere and put up the link ?

Comment: do you actually have any documents with `from` field with an *exact* value of 'a'?

Comment: yo :) I tested many values which were actually there!! nothing turned up :(

Comment: schema.xml link doesn't work for me - I get a blank page, no file downloads either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the schema browser that is present in the solr admin UI to see the values that has been indexed in each field.
2. Also Solr does not do search for query with single character. Try repeating your search with multiple characters as your query.

Comment: I don't know how many characters it starts and all, but I searched like this : _from:infomotions_ which didn't turn out any results.. I am damn sure it has that word in...